# How to print the second word of each line in a text file?

Tags: c, text-files

I have a text file and the lines of text are divided by three strings. How can I print just the second word?

I've tried to print after the blank space (" "), but is not working as supossed to.

The next code prints the first word of each line:

```
void leerEmpleados(){
    FILE *fp;
    struct empleados{
        char codigo[6];
        char nombre[20];
        char apellido[20];
        char departamento[20];
    };

    struct empleados emp;

    fp = fopen("Empleado.txt", "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("El archivo no existe");
    } else {
        //Lee los códigos
        while (!feof(fp)) {
            fscanf(fp,"%s%*[^\n]",emp.codigo);
            printf("%s\n",emp.codigo);
        }

    }
    fclose(fp);
}
```

The file data can contain something like this:
102 John Musician'\n'
103 Paul Musician'\n'
104 Ringo Musician

Comment: Please edit the question, and show an example of the file data

Comment: Please read [Why is “while (!feof(file))” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong)

Comment: @OldProgrammer I've just edited it

Comment: What do you call a string in that file? Do you mean a sentence? From your sample data you might even mean a single word. Please clarify.

Comment: @Gerhardh Yes, I mean a single word. I insert the word as a string that's why I say "string", but you're right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your format string to `" %*s%s%*[^\n]"`.  `%*s` reads the first word on the line and discards it, then `%s` reads the second word.